# Twitter Bootstrap Table reOrder Columns not maintaining order

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have the Twitter bootstrap Table [extension to reorder](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/tree/develop/src/extensions/reorder-columns) the columns which works except when I move the column it just goes back to the same order it was.

Even their [example](http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#extensions/reorder-columns.html) on their site does the same thing. Am I missing something?

```
var $table = $('#table-javascript').bootstrapTable({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'report.php,
    cache: false,
    pagination: true,
    pageSize: 20,
    pageList: [20, 35, 60, 110],
    sortable: true,
    search: true,
    minimumCountColumns: 2,
    reorderableColumns: true,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was with the same bug and after a bit searching I found this open issue on the Bootstrap Table repository: https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/3427

This guy *Guxingzhe* found a way to fix it by changing some lines of code in the **bootstrap-table-reorder-columns.js**.

In the line *~160* you have this slice of code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    columnIndex = that.fieldsColumnsIndex[ths[i]];
    if (columnIndex !== -1) {
        that.columns[columnIndex].fieldIndex = i;
        columns.push(that.columns[columnIndex]);
        that.columns.splice(columnIndex, 1);
    }
}

that.columns = that.columns.concat(columns);
```

Just change it to:

```
for (var i = 0; i < ths.length; i++ ) {
    columnIndex = that.fieldsColumnsIndex[ths[i]];
    that.columns[columnIndex].fieldIndex = i;
    that.fieldsColumnsIndex[ths[i]] = i
    columns.push(that.columns[columnIndex]);
}

that.columns = columns;
```

And that's it! It should work now :)

All credits for this solution goes to https://github.com/Guxingzhe